# INVALID DATA RECEIVED in flightOffers.pricing

Tags: amadeus

I'm getting an "INVALID DATA RECEIVED"/"Flight segment not found" error when making a POST request to /shopping/flight-offers/pricing. I am using data from the flightOffersSearch GET request. I'm just getting started and following the amadeus tutorial, but as far as I can tell my data and code look correct. Since I am just getting started I am running this in the test env.

Here's my data:

```
{"data":{"type":"flight-offers-pricing","flightOffers":[{"type":"flight-offer","id":"1","source":"GDS","instantTicketingRequired":false,"nonHomogeneous":false,"oneWay":false,"lastTicketingDate":"2022-07-27","numberOfBookableSeats":3,"itineraries":[{"duration":"PT2H27M","segments":[{"departure":{"iataCode":"LGA","terminal":"0","at":"2022-11-22T08:05:00"},"arrival":{"iataCode":"ORD","terminal":"2","at":"2022-11-22T09:32:00"},"carrierCode":"DL","number":"1189","aircraft":{"code":"223"},"operating":{"carrierCode":"DL"},"duration":"PT2H27M","id":"1","numberOfStops":0,"blacklistedInEU":false}]}],"price":{"currency":"EUR","total":"103.82","base":"83.00","fees":[{"amount":"0.00","type":"SUPPLIER"},{"amount":"0.00","type":"TICKETING"}],"grandTotal":"103.82"},"pricingOptions":{"fareType":["PUBLISHED"],"includedCheckedBagsOnly":false},"validatingAirlineCodes":["DL"],"travelerPricings":[{"travelerId":"1","fareOption":"STANDARD","travelerType":"ADULT","price":{"currency":"EUR","total":"103.82","base":"83.00"},"fareDetailsBySegment":[{"segmentId":"1","cabin":"ECONOMY","fareBasis":"XAVNA0BQ","brandedFare":"BASICECON","class":"E","includedCheckedBags":{"quantity":0}}]}]}]}}
```

Here's the code:

```
exports.confirmFlight = (req, res, next) => {
//implement the amadeus confirm flight logic
const flight = req.body.flight;

amadeus.shopping.flightOffers.pricing
    .post(
        JSON.stringify({
            data: { type: 'flight-offers-pricing', flightOffers: [flight] },
        })
    )
    .then((response) => {
        res.send(response.result);
        //console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((response) => res.send(response));
```

};

Here's the error:

```
"result": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "code": 4926,
                "title": "INVALID DATA RECEIVED",
                "detail": "Flight segment not found",
                "status": 400
            }
        ]
    },
    "parsed": true
```

Comment: Have you tried to call the Flight Offers Price API with other offers? This message could mean that the offer you try to confirm is not valid anymore.

Comment: @AnnaTsolakou yes! I am making a GET request with the flightOffersSearch call in postman and then copying and pasting one of the flights into the body of the flight-offers-pricing post request. I've tried this several times and I always get this error.